# Chain dropdown thrown error in mvn cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I tried to create a chain dropdown for village, currently succeed create from province to subdistricts.

So i created a Village.java file for filtering:

package com.sun.pro.aub.domain;

```
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringExclude;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

/**
 * Village 4th level.
 * Sub District
 * 
 * @author dev on  1:53:29 PM
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @version 1.0.0
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "villa")
public class Village {

  @ToStringExclude
  @Id
  private Long id;

  String name;

  @ToStringExclude
  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne
  Village village;

  /**
   * Default ctr
   */
  public Village() {

  }

  /**
   * @param id the id
   */
  public Village(Long id) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
  }

  /**
   * @return the subDistrict
   */
  public SubDistrict getSubDistrict() {
    return subDistrict;
  }

  /**
   * @param id
   *        village id
   * @param subDistrictCity
   *        village subDistrict subDistrict
   * @param name
   *        village name
   */
  public Village(Long id, SubDistrict subDistrict, String name) {
    this(id, name);
    this.subDistrict = subDistrict;
  }

  public Village(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * @return the id
   */
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * @param districtCity the districtCity to set
   * @return SubDistrict for convenience chaining
   */
  public Village setSubDistrict(SubDistrict subDistrict) {
    this.subDistrict = subDistrict;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param id the id to set
   * @return SubDistrict for convenience chaining
   */
  public Village setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param name the name to set
   * @return SubDistrict for convenience chaining
   */
  public Village setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Village o1 = (Village) o;
    if (o1.id == null || id == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(id, o1.id);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(id);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE);
  }

}
```

But when run mvn test it throw errors `cannot find symbol subDistrict line 59, 72 and 99` on Village.java file.

This village file quite same withbthe SubDistrict file i created before.

Any suggestions?
Big thanks

Comment: maybe `mvn clean`?

Comment: What's your point? The subDistrict field is not defined in Village class, so it can't compile.